# php SimpleXMLElement weird behaviour

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm using a tool which exports data from a database to an XML file. I'm writing an object which can take the XML file, perform various filters, validations etc etc to it, and import it into a second database.

I have an array which contains the XML field names as keys, and the database table field names as values.

One of my methods loops through each record, then loops through the array of field name translations and builds an array to be used in an CodeIgniter insert_batch statement.

I have a weird problem I've not encountered before, regarding accessing properties from the SimpleXMLElement object dynamically.

This is my current code:

```
    $sql = array();
    foreach($this->current_file as $c => $record){
        $sql[$c] = array();

        foreach($this->schema['tables'][$this->current_file_name]['pairing'] as $sql_field => $xml_field){
            $sql[$c][$sql_field] = $record->$xml_field;
        }
    }
```

On line 5 in the code block above, you can see I look through all the field name translations, and insert values into the $sql array.

```
XML field (echo $xml_field):                  external_id
SQL field (echo $sql_field):                  global_user_id
External ID (echo $record->external_id):      0717d6d0-3ffb-427d-8870-890132191e7b
Dynamic XML field (echo $record->$xml_field): 

Dump of $record:
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[29]
      public 'external_id' => string '0717d6d0-3ffb-427d-8870-890132191e7b' (length=36)
      public 'teacher' => string 'T' (length=1)
      public 'username' => string 'jdoe' (length=9)
      public 'ChosenName' => string 'John' (length=8)
      public 'Surname' => string 'Doe' (length=8)
      public 'Title' => string 'mr' (length=2)
      public 'Gender' => string 'male' (length=4)

Dump of $record->$xml_field ($record->external_id):
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[30]
```

As you can see, if the `$xml_field` value is `external_id`, if I perform the following:

```
echo $record->external_id;
```

It successfully outputs the external ID. However If I do this:

```
$xml_field = 'external_id';
echo $record->$xml_field;
```

It produces an empty string. Infact, `$record->xml_field` returns an SimpleXMLElement object.

**My Question**

Why is it returning an instance of the `SimpleXMLElement` object instead of the property value when I reference the property dynamically? It works fine when the property is hardcoded.

If you required any extra information, please let me know.

Thanks

**Edit**
The contents of the SimpleXMLElement object, after calling `$record->$xml_element` is this:

```
$xml_element = 'external_id';
var_dump($record->$xml_element);

// Outputs:
[external_id] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [0] => 0717d6d0-3ffb-427d-8870-890132191e7b
    )
```

I've tried doing `$record->$xml_element[0]` and `$record->{$xml_element}[0]`, but neither work as expected.

It's as if referencing a property of SimpleXMLElement generates a new SimpleXMLElement

Comment: And what is the content of that new SimpleXMLElement ?

Comment: @ClémentMalet Thanks for the reply, I've updated my question at the bottom with the result

Comment: I've no idea about this behavior, can you try this : `echo (string) $record->$xml_field;` ?

Comment: That seems to have worked, although I thought I had tried this before, but obviously I had a mistake somewhere along the line! Thanks for your response though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it's related with how do you fill the "$xml_field" sometimes you should use type casting when you trying to get data from xml objects.

like `$x = (string)$xml->blablaField;`

otherwise it may return object. Seems like your $xml_field is not a string in your case. Thats why you get object from "$record->$xml_element"

Comment: I thought I had tried typecasting to a string previously and it didn't work, I've just tried it again and it's worked successfully! Very weird, how it requires typecasting on dynamic properties, but not on static values.

Comment: i don't remember very well but i think there are some native methods of SimpleXMLElement like toString(); You may also try them instead of typecasting.